# How to do element-wise comparison with Eigen?

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen

I'm trying to implement the following pseudo-code in C++ using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page):

```
img_binary = +1*(img>img_mean) + -1*(img<img_mean)
```

i.e. i'm trying to convert a gray scale image into a binary image such that values greater than image mean are +1 and less then image mean are -1. So far, I have the following:

```
cv::Mat cv_image
cv_image = cv::imread(img_path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)

MatrixXf eig_image;
cv::cv2eigen(cv_image, eig_image):

float image_mean = eig_image.mean();

ArrayXXf bin_image;
bin_image = eig_image.array() > image_mean;
```

I'm getting an error in the last line saying that I mixed different numeric types. Any suggestion on how I can do element-wise comparisons with Eigen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution in Eigen would be

```
ArrayXXf bin_image = (eig_image.array() > image_mean).cast<float>()*2.f-1.f;
```

An alternative would be:

```
ArrayXXf bin_image = (eig_image.array() > image_mean)
    .select(ArrayXXf::Constant(1.0f,eig_image.rows(),eig_image.cols()), -1.0f);
```

Having to use `ArrayXXf::Constant` for one argument unfortunately is necessary, because there is no `.select` method accepting two scalar values

However, unless you plan to do further processing in Eigen you should consider using the corresponding OpenCV method [`threshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold).

Comment: What if we replace `ArrayXXf` with `Tensor`? The `Eigen::Tensor` class does not have an `array()` method.

Comment: @dshin `Eigen::Tensor` by default already mostly works like `Array`, but it is not 100% API compatible.

Comment: Yes, `Tensor` mostly works like `Array`. But as I wrote in my comment, `Tensor` does not have an `array()` method, and so "mostly" is not good enough here. Is there a way to modify your solution so that it works for `Tensor`?