# Eigen: Comparing each element of vector with constant

Tags: c++, eigen3

is there a way how to compare each element of a vector with a constant? So far, I am comparing 2D vector `Eigen::Vector2d` with a constant `double tolerance` like this:

```cpp
    if (x(0) > tolerance && x(1) > tolerance)
    {
     ...
    }
```

I have found the function `isApprox()` but it did not worked somehow. Is there is a nicer or recommended way on how to do it?

Comment: Please provide [mcve] you can start with this: https://godbolt.org/z/K91zEGh6q

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009258/how-to-do-element-wise-comparison-with-eigen

Comment: After last edit it smells like [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please [edit] your question and start from explaining what you are calculating and why you think your approach of comparing each element to constant  is good approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `array` method of the `Vector` class.  Like this:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Eigen::Vector2d A{ 7.5, 8.2 };
    std::cout << A << '\n';
    auto res = A.array() >= 8.0;
    std::cout << res << '\n';
    if (res.all()) {
        std::cout << "True" << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "False" << '\n';
    }

    A(0) = 10.2;
    auto res2 = A.array() >= 8.0;
    std::cout << res2 << '\n';
    if (res2.all()) {
        std::cout << "True" << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "False" << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this case `res` and `res2` are `CwiseBinaryOp` which contains booleans for each element in `A`.  Use `all` to find when both are `True`.

Comment: improved version https://godbolt.org/z/xsTxGzPsM

Comment: @MarekR Thanks for the suggestions, there are many ways to improve this further.  You can turn it into a one liner with `if ((A.array() > 8.0).all()) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a good call on this one is to write a simple function:

```cpp
bool is_componentwise_greater_than(
    Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd const> const &vector, double lower_bound) {
  for (auto value : vector) {
    if (value <= lower_bound)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

The drawback of this way compared to the solution by @Matt is, that for more complicated use cases, using an Eigen expression can be more performant (no idea, if this applies here).

The (in my opinion huge) advantage of such an solution is, that you
can see exactly what it does from its usage.

Of course you can also pack Matts solution in an aptly named function to get this advantage. Another advantage is, that with the function I provided you know exactly what it does and never have to wonder, whether using auto with an Eigen type could bite you. I guess it won't and Matt probably knows exactly why. But I (and you?) do not and therefore wouldn't want to rely on it.